# How to copy an array in Typescript and add a new field to the copied array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a person array. The person object has a fields of name and age. I want to copy the person array and add a new field (country) to the person object array. The country field comes from an array of strings. So the fields of object of the new array will have a fields of name, age and country. Here's my plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/chBRHn0FCGNT6Ts15fAz?p=preview

```
`export class App {
  index: number =0;
  countries: string [] = ['US', 'UK'];

  constructor() {
    this.persons = [
    {'name':'Marvin','age': 12}, 
    {'name':'Carla','age': 15}
    ];
    this.newPersons = this.persons.map(function(person){
      return {
        name:person.name,
        age : person.age
      }
    });
  }
}`
```

Comment: An array doesn't have fields. What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: My bad. sorry I updated my question. What I want to say is an array of person object in which that object has a fields of name and age.

Comment: Still: where's the code?

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ Are you looking for [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: Do you mean you have an array of objects? 
something like 

`[{name:"jhon", age:"18"},{name:"jerry", age:"19"}]`

and you want it to change to something like 
 `[{name:"jhon", age:"18", gender:"male"},{name:"jerry", age:"19", gender:"female"}]`

Comment: yeah that's what exactly I want to do. the gender field comes from an array of string let say gender: string [] = ['male', 'female'].

Comment: How do you still have a question? Update the `return` to add whatever additional fields you want.

Comment: I dont know how to add the each string of the array to the new field.

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ you have 3 countries in string array and only 2 objects in your persons array, how do you want the end result to look like? Having trouble with that since the length of the arrays are different :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As we found out, there is no need for a second array, but the country field should be added to the existing `persons`-array. This we can do with a simple for loop, where we push add a new property `country` to the `persons` array and the corresponding value from the `countries` array based on index:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.persons.length; i++) {
  this.persons[i].country = this.countries[i]
}
```

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zeCez7x4AQRqfNRq4T5M?p=preview)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I guess you want the corresponding index of of the two arrays combined, this will do that:

```
// local variable to increment in map to get corresponding value of index in 'countries' array
i: number = 0;

this.newPersons = this.persons.map(a => Object.assign({name:a.name, age:a.age,country:this.countries[this.i++]}));
```

This results in the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Marvin",
    "age": 12,
    "country": "US"
  },
  {
    "name": "Carla",
    "age": 15,
    "country": "UK"
  }
]
```

Your **[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/EgtZQRAZOmZHGnVSa9H0?p=preview)**

Comment: I have a question is the changes in newPerson will be reflected into the original person?

Comment: Nope, it will not be reflected, since this does not have a reference to the original array.

Comment: What is the best way? Do I need to map the newPerson back to person array?

Comment: Do you actually not want to have two separate arrays, but just one with the country set? If so, you could just add the country field to your existing array.

Comment: Yeah as much as possible I don't want to create a new array. But I want to add a new field in the object to which from what I know the best possible thing to do is to map a new array and add the new field in each object. Do you have any suggestion on how I can add a new field in the object without the need of mapping/copying a new array?